# Background-image being cut off when trying to make it fit around the element

Tags: html, css, background-image

[image: the video borders in this image are how I am trying to mine to look The picture on top of the border keeps cutting out on top.]I am trying to get my `background-image` to fit around my video and every time I try making it bigger the top get cut off and I can't seem to make it actually fit around the video and look good.

I want the image to be a border to my video. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the image going out side the video div, but I could be mistaken. Any help appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="videos">
    <div id="video1">
        <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vr0dXfQQfNU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="video2">
        <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fevkx229XBs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <!--h <img src="images/vidborder2.png" class="vidborder2">-->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#video1 {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(images/vidborder.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
div#video2 {
    background-image: url(images/vidborder2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 80%;
    background-position: center;
}
.videos {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: This is hard to test because I don't have access to the images that you are using for borders, but try adding padding to both div#video1  and div#video2. Does that help?

Comment: hey tylerism i added a photo

Comment: Why not just add a border to the video.  border:10px solid grey; Here is an example: http://codepen.io/tylerism/pen/KpZGNV

Comment: because i added texture in photoshop and the image on top of the border. Not sure if I should just add the image in html and position it. Trying to figure out what the best practice would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got very close to the solution.

> I am pretty sure it has something to do with the image going out side the video div, but I could be mistaken.

The image won't go outside the `div`.

For the image to look like the border of the video, we have to add `padding` to the `div`. (Also mentioned by @tylerism in comments)

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cksk6La9/).

Following are the changes I did in your code.

```
text-align: center;
background-size: 80%;
```

```
padding: 10px 10px;
```

I used this [image](http://freedesignfile.com/upload/2012/12/Snow_backgrounds-2.jpg) for testing purpose. You can replace the url.

Comment: This only seem to add padding to the bottom. I added a picture to show how I want my border to look. The picture at the top of my border keep cutting off.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
padding : 10px;
background-size: cover;
```

http://jsbin.com/juguxenufi/edit?css,output